# Minimising Posterior expected loss

Tags: bayesian, inference, posterior, conditional-expectation, point-estimation

I am new to Bayesian statistics. I am not sure how I could find the best point estimator $T(x)$ for $\alpha$ that minimises the posterior expected loss, $$E_{\alpha|x} [L(\alpha, T(x)))] = \int L(\alpha, T(x)) p(\alpha|x) d\alpha$$. 
Assuming we have zero-one loss.

Thanks to anyone who may be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the $0-1$ loss function is defined as
$$L(\alpha,t)=1-\mathbb I_\alpha(t)=\begin{cases}
1 &\text{ if }t\ne\alpha\\
0 &\text{ if }t=\alpha
\end{cases}$$
and if the posterior distribution of $\alpha$ is absolutely continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure, the posterior probability that $\alpha=t$ is zero for every value of $t$, i.e.,
$$\mathbb E_{\alpha|x} [L(\alpha, t)] = \int_A L(\alpha, t) p(\alpha|x) \,\text d\alpha=1$$
meaning that every value of $t$ has the same posterior loss.

Comment: Thanks, I saw your comment above and was reading my notes again to try and address it. This was not obvious to me,